# Watir-Classic not clicking on element

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

```
<span class="titleBar-link">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-click-handler="openBYOTView,omnitureClickHandler"     data-omniture-rfrr="ROUNDTRIP">
<span data-icon="roundtrip"></span>See Roundtrip Combinations
</a>
</span>
```

From the above HTML code, I want to click on element `<span class="titleBar-link">`, for that I used the following code

```
Browser. span(:class => 'titleBar-link').click
```

When I am running this code with IE(Watir-Classic), this step was executed but really it didn’t click on that element. It worked well with Watir-Webdriver.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking the link instead?

```
browser.span(:class => 'titleBar-link').link.click
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use

```
browser.link(:xpath => "//span[@class='titleBar-link']/a[0]").click
```

Comment: Using :xpath is really not recommended, since it is slow and looks ugly.

Comment: The question was not about recommended method, it was about solution. Yes, xpath is ugly but watir is not the perfect solution. It is open-source and getting mature so you have to use xpath some times.

Comment: @amjad: Watir is pretty mature, and Jarmo knows it, he is one of the developers. :)

Comment: I see, may be I am not up-to-dated :). Thanks